# Windows PATH seems broken in Git Bash

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

I installed MySQL and wanted to see if it worked well, testing it on Git Bash (the course told me to do so). The code I had to write was the following one: `export PATH=/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/:$PATH`.

The main issue is that every time I open again Git Bash there are several lines saying **not a valid identifier**. I can't provide an image as I'm new, but one of the examples might be:

> bash: export: `Corporation/NVIDIA': not a valid identifier

Although I deleted Git Bash and reinstalled again, the problem persists. Does anyone know how to fix that on Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the path contains spaces, it needs to be quoted:

```
export PATH="/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/:$PATH"
```

You need to change this in whatever file you originally wrote this line in; it's probably named `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and can be found in your home directory (typically `c:\Users\YourUsername`).

Comment: Oh, I understand, my bad there with not quoting.

For changing this, how can I find the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`? I'm currently on Git Bash, using **ls** and **ls -l** but I can't find it. 

Sorry for those basic questions, but I'm new to that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Files starting with a dot are hidden from `ls` by default. Use `ls -a` to reveal them. Once you're in the right folder, you can edit the file with `nano .bashrc` (or another editor of your choice instead of `nano`).

Comment: @VictorLJ Try the command `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2` mentioned in this answer, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154971. I tested it and it worked in Git Bash. It prints where the environment variables are defined and exported.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thomas! I removed the PATH with spaces and now everything is fine!

Comment: Hello @ElpieKay, seems that modifying the `.bash_profile` with `nano` everything is solved. I closed Git Bash, open it again and there's no more **no valid identifier**. I will keep your answer too in case it happens again (hope not haha).